# Who can help me with a key list in C?

Tags: c

That's my application code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};

void push(struct node** head_ref, int new_data) {
  struct node* new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  new_node->data = new_data;
  new_node->next = (*head_ref);
  (*head_ref) = new_node;
}

void deleteKey(struct node **head_ref, int key) {
  struct node* temp = *head_ref, *prev;
  while (temp != NULL && temp->data == key) {
    *head_ref = temp->next;   // Changed head
    free(temp);               // free old head
    temp = *head_ref;         // Change Temp
  }

  while (temp != NULL) {
    while (temp != NULL && temp->data != key) {
      prev = temp;
      temp = temp->next;
    }
    if (temp == NULL) return;
    prev->next = temp->next;
    free(temp);  // Free memory
    temp = prev->next;
  }
}

void printList(struct node *node) {
  while (node != NULL) {
    printf(" %d ", node->data);
    node = node->next;
  }
}

int main() {
  struct node* head = NULL;

  push(&head, 7);
  push(&head, 2);
  push(&head, 3);
  push(&head, 2);
  push(&head, 8);
  push(&head, 1);
  push(&head, 2);
  push(&head, 2);

  int key = 2; // key to delete

  puts("Created Linked List: ");
  printList(head);

  deleteKey(&head, key);
  puts("\nLinked List after Deletion of 1: ");

  printList(head);
  return 0;
}
```

Requirements :

```
#ifndef LNKDLST_H_
#define LNKDLST_H_
/*
 * Function : Initialises the list
 * Purpose : Ensures that pointers are set to point to the right thing
  If the lists exists already it is emptied before
  initialising a new.
  * Return : 1 indicates success, 0 error
 
 int initialise ();
 /*
  * Function : put
  * Purpose : Add data mapped with key to the end of the list
  * Return : 1 indicates success, 0 error
 
 int put (int key, void *data);
 /*
  * Function : get
  * Purpose : Get the first item in the list and return the data
  * Return : A pointer to the data, NULL on error

 void *get ();
 /*
  * Function : getKeyd
  * Purpose : Get the item with key and return the data
  * Return : A pointer to the data, NULL on error
 
 void *getKeyd (int key);
 /*
  * Function : isEmpty
  * Purpose : Checks if the list is empty
  * Return : 1 to indicate an empty list, 0 a non empty list
 
 int isEmpty();
 /*
  * Function : exists
  * Purpose : Checks if the item with key exists in the list
  * Return : 1 if key exists, 0 if not
 
 int exists (int key);
 #endif
```

I have tried to redesign the program to fulfill the requirements but I find it very difficult to follow. Do I need to make another program or it's possible to redesign this one?

This is a **homework task**, however I'm stuck and cannot figure out how it needs to be done properly.

Comment: `while (temp != NULL && temp->data == key) {...}` This only loops when the key happens to be first on the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood it right, you want to achieve the requirements by using the program you wrote above. 

It possible to re-design it using your own code.

eg : For  get()

```
struct node *get(int key, void *data)
{
    if(*head_ref != NULL)
    {
        key = *head_ref->data;
        return *head_ref;
    }
    else
    { 
        printf("Error in retrieving data from head of list\n");
    }
}
```

In this way you can use code from your program and modify it slightly to achieve what is asked. 
The first node that you visit, if the list does exist- is the head of the list. You are asked to return a pointer to the head of the list and also copy the data in that node into variable 'key'.
If you are still having trouble, i would suggest you go through linked list concept once more to be sure you won't have any trouble. You can refer to Youtube to find videos on these concepts.